# RxJava Completable.andThen never triggers the second Completable

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java, rx-java-completable

I'm trying to chain two reactive calls which return `Completable` using retrofit on android:

```
val userRequest = ...
val languageRequest = ...

return userService.updateUser(userRequest)
    .andThen { userService.updateMessagingUserLanguages(user.id, languageRequest) }
    .doOnComplete { userRepository.updateUser(user) }
```

which are defined as follow:

```
@PUT("$BASE_USER_URL")
fun updateUser(@Body user: UserRequest): Completable

@PUT("$BASE_URL/{userId}/languages")
fun updateMessagingUserLanguages(@Path("userId") userId: Long, @Body request: MessagingLanguageDTO): Completable
```

The first `Completable` succeed and returns a response with a 200 status. However, the second call is never triggered (it never appears in my log and does not pass my breakpoint).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
andThen(userService.updateMessagingUserLanguages(user.id, languageRequest))
```

IOW, replace the lambda expression as a parameter with the actual `Completable` that you want to add to the chain.

Comment: Two hours and one lambda less later, here we are... Thank you!

Comment: @Benjamin: It's almost like I've made this mistake before! Repeatedly!  I'm glad that it is working for you!